# SharedArrayBuffer inside Chrome Extension Sandboxed iFrame

Tags: sandbox, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

I am trying to use `SharedArrayBuffer` by setting up a document that is cross-origin isolated. However since it is in a Google Chrome extension and I need WebAssembly, I need to run this inside a sandboxed page.

I have a sandboxed page which is defined as such in my manifest.json

```json
{
    ...
    "sandbox": {
        "pages": ["sandbox.html"]
    },
    "content_security_policy": {
        "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self' 'wasm-eval'; script-src-elem 'self' 'wasm-eval' blob:; worker-src 'self' blob:"
    },
    "cross_origin_embedder_policy": {
        "value": "require-corp"
    },
    "cross_origin_opener_policy": {
        "value": "same-origin"
    },
    ...
}
```

and I have also enabled cross-origin isolation with COOP and COEP.

The `sandbox.html` does nothing except use this script:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const thing = document.createElement('h1');
    thing.innerHTML = self.crossOriginIsolated ? 'GOOD am crossOriginIso' : 'BAD am not crossOriginIso';
    document.body.appendChild(thing);
});
```

Then I have a page `outer.html` which embeds `sandbox.html` in an iFrame.

```html
<iframe src="sandbox.html" allow="cross-origin-isolated"></iframe>
```

When I open `outer.html`, I get the message "BAD am not crossOriginIso", ie the `sandbox.html` document inside the iFrame is not cross-origin isolated (and I cannot use `SharedArrayBuffer`).

**Is there a way to enable cross-origin isolation in a Chrome extension with manifest v3 in an iFrame where the inner document is sandboxed (through `manifest.json`).**

Perhaps more specifically, **how does one add more `featurePolicy.allowedFeatures()` to a sandbox iFrame (which is sandboxed in the Chrome extension's `manifest.json`, not with the `sandbox` attribute).**

I have noted the following things:

- Opening `sandbox.html` directly without the iFrame, the page is cross-origin isolated.
- Removing the `sandbox` attribute in `manifest.json` results in the document inside the iframe to be cross-origin isolated.
- Executing `document.featurePolicy.allowedFeatures()` inside the iFrame gives a very small list of features (and doesn't include `cross-origin-isolated`). This list is a lot smaller than executing the same command when opening `sandbox.html` directly.

Answer (score 1):

In chrome 103, manifest v3, that works well

```
 "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "default-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval';style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' "
  },
  "cross_origin_embedder_policy": {
    "value": "require-corp"
  },
  "cross_origin_opener_policy": {
    "value": "same-origin"
  },
```

don't use sandbox to run ffmpeg.wasm, SharedArrayBuffer is not available in sandbox